# SQL query for getting count on same table using left outer join

Tags: sql, join, group-by

I have a table from which I need to get the count grouped on two columns.

The table has two columns one `datetime` column and another one is success value(-1,1,0)
What i am looking for is something like this:

Count of success value for each month:

month----success-----count 
11-------  -1 -------        50

11-------  1  ---------       50

11-------  0   -------      50

12-------  -1   -------      50

12-------  1   -------     50

12-------  0    -------   50

If there is no success value for a month then the count should be `null` or zero.
I have tried with left outer join as well but of no use it gives the count incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cross join all the available months, against the 3 success values to build a virtual matrix, which can then be left joined to the actual data

```
select m.month, s.success, COUNT(t.month)
from (select distinct MONTH from tbl) m
cross join (select -1 success union all select 1 union all select 0) s
left join tbl t on t.month = m.month and t.success = s.success
group by m.month, s.success
```

If you need missing months as well, that can be done, just slightly more complicated by changing the subquery "m" above.

@updated
Count(*) will always return at least 1 for left joins.  count(colname) from the right part of the left join to be correct.

Comment: hi the query returns the number of rows as expected but for a particular month the count is returned as 1 where as it should be zero :(

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a table with the just the values from 1-12 to join with so you can get a zero count.